# Which Windows versions include where with shebang support?

Tags: windows, shebang

I am using [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win) and discovered that in my Windows version (20H2 19042.1165), `where.exe` supports scripts with shebang:

```
C:\> where python
C:\Users\ded\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python
C:\Users\ded\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python.bat
```

First python file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
pyenv exec $(basename "$0") "$@"
```

What is the magic? Is is native shebang support in `where.exe`? Which Windows version include this feature?

PS: Running `python` in a `cmd` will execute `python.bat` not `python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where.exe` is finding a file in the path with the name you specified.  If there is no extension, it also tries all extensions listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable.  Your file doesn't need a shebang to be found.

Below creates a few text files and `where` finds the no-extension one as well as the one with an extension listed in `PATHEXT`:

```
C:>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw

C:>echo >abc

C:>echo >abc.txt

C:>echo >abc.bat

C:>where abc
C:\abc
C:\abc.bat
```